# Why does Microsoft Edge read PDF files but cannot preview them in Google Drive Web service?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, google, pdf, lumia-640-xl, microsoft-edge

Despite that Microsoft Edge has PDF viewing capabilities, it can't preview pdf files shared with me via Google Drive service. Can someone explain Why does this happen?

My phone is Lumia 640 XL running Windows 10 Mobile

This problem happens with any pdf files even photos shared through Google drive service. There isn't any problem with these files using Chrome browser previewing either pdfs or photos on my desktop.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "can't preview". What exactly happens when you try to open a PDF from Google Drive? Are you sure Google Drive is actually serving you a PDF? Does the same link work on a PC (in Edge or another browser)?

Comment: Could you translate that error message to English?

Comment: Sorry! A problem has occurred while loading this page.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in Google services, pdf files are opened as a preview within the website by their services and is not displayed by the browser. It appears as a pop-up in the websites. This is similar to a web app. Microsoft Edge mobile version cannot render that type of web pages it seems.

---

The best way is to download the pdf and view it Edge or in another pdf reader.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that Microsoft's Edge browser is the problem. I  have applied the above scenario with One Drive service. The browser can't even preview photos. It's shameful that Microsoft leave their loyal customers with such terrible reliability, and bad user experience without fixing it.